# SearchBar doesn’t update the value when it comes as props along with the setter from it´s parent

Tags: reactjs, components, state, react-native

I want 'SearchBar' (react native element) to be in another component, where the parent component takes care of the content state

```
const SearchScreen = () => {
    const [term, setTerm] = useState('');

    return (
        <View>
            <MySearchbar
                placeholderText="Type your search..."
                onTermChange={(text) => setTerm(text)}
                term={term}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Where MySearchBar is

```
const MySearchbar = ({ onTermChange, term, placeholderText }) => {
    return (
        <SearchBar
            darkTheme
            placeholder={placeholderText}
            onTextChange={onTermChange}
            value={term}
        />
    );
};
```

With this approach, when I type something, the value appears but disappears instantly as if the value term wasn’t updated with the new value

But if I place the SearchBar directly on the 'SearchScreen' component, it all works fine

Why isn’t the state value 'term' updated?

Rafael

Comment: is it `onTextChange` or `onChangeText` ?

Answer (score 0):

Primarily which you need to consider is render methods getting called. Try to console log the setter of search bar and you will see that after rendering again because of that state you have in father component, it will change props, render again and call setter.

My approach would be to set that same state inside search bar and to change the setter to the correct nomenclature: onChangeText

Comment: No, it didn´t. I think it is related to events, the event to update is not firing